# Add multiple signature blocks into excel document using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using vba to create an excel document and fill it in dynamically (already completed and working perfectly).  What I need is:  to figure out how to add, size, position, and prefill (suggested signer, email, but not the signature itself) the signature block at multiple locations in this document.
I don't even know if this can be done with vba (my searches on the subject have been unhelpful), but I'm hopeful as it will save me a lot of time and tedious work in the future.  Any help on this would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to place simple text boxes across defined cells (as anchor points) and fill it with some text. To get you started here's the bare minimum that you need:

the actual text box creating Sub which takes all info as parameters:

```
Sub CreateShapeText(NailToCell As Range, w_pt As Single, h_pt As Single, DTxt As String)
Dim TB As Shape

    ' create a text box shape
    ' note: shapes belong to worksheets, therefore we derive a WS from cell.parent
    Set TB = NailToCell.Parent.Shapes.AddLabel(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, NailToCell.Left, NailToCell.Top, w_pt, h_pt)

    ' make its border visible
    TB.Line.Visible = msoTrue

    ' switch off that annoying auto-resize when text is entered
    TB.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeNone

    ' enter text ... and yes - this object tree is crazy
    TB.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = DTxt

    ' as it should be - text is vertical bottom 
    ' but to have more control over the TB, this could be a parameter, too
    TB.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorBottom

End Sub
```

and you would call that from wherever in your code as in below example

```
Sub CallCreate()

    CreateShapeText [A1], 132, 32, "sign: me"
    CreateShapeText [C12], 132, 32, "sign: you"

End Sub
```

You take it from here and research what these objects can do for you (e.g. make dotted lines instead of solid for the frame, experiment with font sizes, alignments etc.) and come back with more questions in case ...

Comment: I apologize, for not being clear in my original post.  I am trying to use some variation of:    workbooks("Book1").Signatures.AddSignatureLine

Comment: Using the ".Signatures.Addsignatureline" I get a signature box to pop up asking for details. Unfortunately, I need 28 signature boxes per document (more than 30 of these documents are needed at a time), so I'm trying to find a way for VBA to fill in these details without the popup occurring.

Comment: *aaahh* ... now at least it becomes clear why we ask for some context and/or source code to be included in a question *ggg*

Comment: in contrary to Word, Excel doesn't allow the `Add` method which would allow configuring the `Signature`object so I'm afraid you're left with `AddSignatureLine` which pops up the Dialog box ... you may need to redesign the process rather than search for code ?!?

Comment: I've been grudgingly coming to the same conclusion.  Thank you for you help in this matter.